# Не работает one с animatenamber

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуста, почему просчитывается несколько раз к заданому числу. Мне нужно чтоб один раз. One не работает с animatenamber

```
<HTML>

<HEAD>
    <TITLE>onScroll Event Handler</TITLE>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animateNumber.js"></script>

</head>

<BODY>
    <table>
        <tr height="3000">
            <td>v</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>This plugin only <span id="lines">0</span> lines of code.</p>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(window).scroll(function () {
                        var bo = $("body").scrollTop();
                        if (bo > 2000)
                            $('#lines').animateNumber({
                                number: 35000
                            }, 500);
                        return;
                    });
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: а кто такой этот animateNumber ? плагин ? лучше всего спросить у автора.

Comment: так и это.. у вас это на scroll висит, так и вешайте one на scroll

    $(window).one('scroll',function(){

Comment: @eicto, это ТС не поможет. До 2000px он недоскроллит. Тут скорее всего нужен флаг, на который ориентироваться. Доскроллил до 2000, поставил флаг, запустил плагин.

Comment: а ну да, я как-то не обратил внимание чего он там делает.

Comment: Тоисть callback функцию нужно использовать или как? А какую именно?
animateNumber - это плагин.
http://aishek.github.io/jquery-animateNumber/

Comment: просто напишите 

   if (bo > 2000 && !window.wasAnimateNumber) {
       window.wasAnimateNumber=true;
       //...

Comment: Дописал но никакой реакции(((

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var bo = $("body").scrollTop(), bof = false;
    if (bo > 2000) {
        if (!bof) $('#lines').animateNumber({number: 35000}, 500);
        bof = true;
    } else {
        if (bof) $('#lines').animateNumber({number: 0}, 500); // типа того
        bof = false;
    }
    return;
});
```

Comment: Нет. Тоже не работает